# Change color and stop a function after clicking ( only JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table with few rows of cells. My task is to set the cell after being clicked, the cell value will be delivered to a div block "Seat Booked". I did this but there are still some requirements that I have to fulfill. After clicking the table cell(which is a seat number), the background color of the cell will change permanently and the cell is not clickable anymore. How can I edit my codes to add these 2 requirements ? By the way, only JavaScript is allowed. Thank you :D

```
<table id="tab">
<caption>SCREEN</caption>
<tr>
    <td>A1</td>
    <td>A2</td>
    <td>A3</td>
    <td>A4</td>
    <td>A5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>B1</td>
    <td>B2</td>
    <td>B3</td>
    <td>B4</td>
    <td>B5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>C1</td>
    <td>C2</td>
    <td>C3</td>
    <td>C4</td>
    <td>C5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>D1</td>
    <td>D2</td>
    <td>D3</td>
    <td>D4</td>
    <td>D5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>E1</td>
    <td>E2</td>
    <td>E3</td>
    <td>E4</td>
    <td>E5</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var table = document.getElementById("tab");
    if (table != null) {
        for (var i = 0; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
            for (var j = 0; j < table.rows[i].cells.length; j++)
                table.rows[i].cells[j].onclick = function () { getval(this)};
        }
    }
    function getval(cel) {
        let seatno = document.createElement("h3");
        seatno.innerHTML = cel.innerHTML;
        document.getElementById("stbk").appendChild(seatno);  
    }
</script>
```

Comment: `cel.onclick = null; cel.className = 'foobar';` And then add a rule in your stylesheet that sets the background color for those cells that now have the class `foobar`.

Comment: if you can set up vote also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that easy just follow this ways.
you just have to add a class `clicked` for the `td` and in javascript set a condition to if `td` has class don't do any job;

```js
var tdTag = document.querySelectorAll("#tab tr td");

for(var i = 0; i < tdTag.length; i++){
  tdTag[i].addEventListener('click', clickedFunction);
}

function clickedFunction(){
  if(!this.classList.contains('clicked')){
      this.classList.add('clicked');
      this.style.background = "red";
  }
}
```